# Google assistant on boot on raspberry

Tags: raspberry-pi, google-assistant-sdk

I've successfully installed google assistant sdk on a rapberry pi, everything is working, but there is something I haven't managed to do : make it start on boot.
I'm using hotword.py, I know I have to use a system service, but I don't know what to put in the script, It was easier with the voicekit, but now i'm stuck ...

Thank you if you have an answer !

jerome

Comment: For Raspbian or Android Things?

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps.

https://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2015/02/how-to-autorun-a-python-script-on-raspberry-pi-boot/

I'm doing it now on my Pi with Google-assistant

Comment: Thank you it does the job ! I've also found a way to start at boot with a system service. Thank you